# nrf51822 + ST-Link V2 Debugging

Tags: debugging, stm32, openocd, nrf51

I'm working on a project where I need to program an `NRF51822` using an `ST-Link V2` (*well, perhaps I don't have to do it this way, but that's what I'm currently doing/own*).

I'm pretty sure it's running properly, but I really need a debug console to get some information back from the `NRF51` module to make sure things are connected OK.

I'm not going to lie:

- I'm really quite new to this, and most of my success thus far has been thanks to quite in-depth tutorials.
- I'm using ubuntu and openOCD for programming
- I'm not sure what I need to put in my program in order to get debug/console info out (and I'm not even sure what I would do to receive it on my computer).

I would really appreciate some help on:

1. What to add to my program to log info to the console, and
2. How to view that debug console on my computer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: ST-Link V2 what exactly one you have, STM-original, form the nucleo/discovery board or the Chinese one? All work but yoo will need to define configuration files.

Comment: It's the chinese one, the small usb-flash-drive looking one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use such OpenOCD config file to connect with ST-Link

```
#nRF51822 Target
source [find interface/stlink-v2-1.cfg]

transport select hla_swd

set WORKAREASIZE 0x4000
source [find target/nrf51.cfg]
```

You need to insert your version stlink-v2-1.cfg or stlink-v2.cfg

Also you need to add this to your makefile to write program

```
flash: $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(HEX)
    $(OPENOCD) -d2 -f $(TEMPLATEROOT)/openocd.cfg -c 'init_reset halt; program $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(HEX) verify; reset; exit'
```

Debug is more complex. You'd better set eclipse with OpenOCD/GDB to make it. For console solution you can follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYxEWDpw0g8&t=141s) lesson

This worked for me. Good luck.

Comment: I've got the flashing working properly, it's the debugging I'm struggling with.  Right now I've got it ghetto'd to the point where I can send serial debug through an arduino to get it to a serial monitor on the computer.  That's... not ideal.  I'm trying to figure out how I can print debug strings back through the st-link to get back to the computer.